# Платежная система Liqpay(Android)

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity

Пытаюсь реализовать платежную системы Liqpay на андроид(6+) 
Вроде в туториале написано все понятно, вот только в результате на платформе андроида до 5й версии все работает нормально а на 6й и выше просто появляется белый экран. Ниже прикрепляю код всех активностей которы используются

Тут мы формируем запрос с параметрами

```
public class PayPackAge extends AppCompatActivity{

public class SendStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        new PostExample().PostSendMessage("status", object.toString(), "user_id", userID);
        return null;
    }
}

OkHttpClient client;
JSONObject object;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    client = new OkHttpClient();

    LiqPayCallBack callBack = new LiqPayCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseSuccess(final String resp) {
            object = null;
            try {
                object = new JSONObject(resp);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if("success".equals(object.optString("status"))){
                new SendStatus().execute();
                String cardToken = object.optString("card_token");
            } else {
                new SendStatus().execute();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponceError(final ErrorCode errorCode) {

        }
    };

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("version", "3");
    map.put("public_key", "***");
    map.put("action", "pay");
    map.put("amount", "80");
    map.put("currency", "UAH");
    map.put("description", "Оплата: Пакет 20");
    map.put("order_id", String.valueOf(Math.random()*999999));
    map.put("language", "ru");
    map.put("server_url", "http://***.gq");
    map.put("sandbox", "1");
    String privateKey = "**";
    LiqPay.checkout(getApplicationContext(), map, privateKey, callBack);
```

Объявляем в манифесте

`<activity android:name="ua.privatbank.paylibliqpay.CheckoutActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".PayPackAge"/>`

И переход на активность

```
pay80.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PayPackAge.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

В тех.поддержке Liqpay молчат на эту тему
Ссылка на туториал
https://www.liqpay.com/ru/doc/aos

Подскажите, по какой причине на андроиде до 5й версии подгружается их активность при вызове PayPackAge а андроиде 6+ версии просто белый экран

Comment: Наверное в разрешениях всё дело. Попробуйте на 6 версии вручную их включить чрез список всех приложений

Comment: Можливо потрібно використовувати https://m.privatbank.ua/spec/aos/ як вони рекомендують?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело было в правах на доступ к чтению данных телефона, без них форма LiqPay даже не отображала `Activity`,в документации увы это не описано!